# ¿ Cómo ver el valor de un input type number?

Tags: javascript

En HTML he puesto un input para número y lo he modificado para que tenga botones y que se vea bien visualmente, solo que en este momento quisiera saber como se puede ver el valor de este input ya que leí que se puede utilizar el id para obtener el valor con javascript y luego mostrarlo en consola; también que tiene el metodó change.

Esto es lo que esta en el HTMl

```
<input type="number" value="1" step="1" min="1" max="5" name="num-cant-prod" id="num-cant-prod">
```

Y esto es lo que intente mediante JavaScript en un archivo externo

```
let aux = document.getElementById('num-cant-prod');
aux.addEventListener('change',(event)=>{
   let cant = document.getElementById('num-cant-prod').value;
   console.log(cant);
});
```

también intente haciendo una función en javascript y luego en la etiqueta del `<input>` llamar a dicha función en el evento onchange pero me salía en la consola que la función no estaba definida en el HTMLInputElement.onchange mientras que mediante la opción de fuente en la herramienta para desarrollador si puede visualizar la función en el archivo.

```
function cambio() {
   let cant = document.getElementById('num-cant-prod').value;
   console.log(cant);
}
```

```
<input type="number" value="1" step="1" min="1" max="5" name="num-cant-prod" id="num-cant-prod" onchange="javascript: cambio()">
```

**Talvez alguna solución para esto?**

Comment: Estás solo controlando el "change", por lo que al momento de cambiar, se registra bien el valor. https://jsfiddle.net/rozj8gLu/

Comment: ok, pero si esta bien debería imprimir en consola el valor del input pero ni eso me muestra

Comment: Cuando cambias el valor, si se muestra, por que tu estas analizando el "change" -> prueba: https://i.gyazo.com/0aa25f83584186a01c9ed6be91537867.mp4

Comment: claro, si lo pude ver en el fiddle; todavía no en el navegador. Gracias

Comment: Si quieres ver el valor cada que se modifica el campo (tecleo, cortar, pegar, borrar, etc.), cambia el evento `change` por `input`. El primero se dispara al terminar de modificar (pierde el foco) y, el segundo, siempre que hay una entrada que cambia el valor.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas noches

Esta es una de las tantas soluciones a tu inconveniente veo en tu código que estas tratando de mostrar en la consola el valor de un input de tipo number te propongo esta solución.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" value="1" step="1" min="1" max="5" name="num-cant-prod" id="num-cant-prod">

    <p id="texto"></p> <!--La utilizo para mostrar el dato del input number-->

    <script>

        const input = document.querySelector("input"); // seleccione el elemento input number
        const valueInput = document.getElementById("texto"); // selecciona la etiqueta p donde mostraremos el dato del input number

        input.addEventListener('change',requireValue); //el addEventListener recibe dos parametros  toma el evento change  y lo pone a escuchar, y un segundo argumento para llamar cada vez que se desencadena el evento descrito.

        function requireValue(e) { //mostramos el valor del input number siempre y cuando el usuario haga un cambio.
            valueInput.innerText = "el valor del input text es " + e.target.value;
        } 

        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Aclaro que el evento change no es utilizado precisamente para obtener datos que un usuario escribe en un input, es utilizado para cuando el usuario esta escribiendo algo en el input y haga un cambio mientras escribe en el input se ejecuta este evento.

si vas a la consola de chrome y escribes input.value te mostrara el valor del dato que se encuentra en el input number.

espero te sirva te dejo documentación aquí abajo, éxitos!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event